# Our copy of Mansion of Madness, second edition doesn't contain the original 8 investigators cards, is this correct?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

we had Mansion of Madness, second edition (core game) for Christmas (don't have the original) but the game doesn't have the original 8 investigators. Is this correct? We have 16 other investigators cards. The box say it should come with 8 with matching 8 figures, we have 8 figures but 16 cards. (Not sure if they match) the game comes with a conversion pack which it says has the 16 extra cards. Are we missing the 8 investigator cards??
I'm so confused! 
Thanks for any help. 
(The box was all sealed, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be correct. From the second-edition rulebook, page 4, "First Game" sidebar:

> Before choosing a scenario, if you own the first edition *Mansions of Madness* base game and/or any of its expansions, you can integrate the components of those products as described by the *Conversion Kit* rules insert.
>
> Players can play any investigators from the integrated first edition products, and the app can use any of the monsters or map tiles from those products during the game.

I think it's reasonable to infer that the original investigators (and monsters and map tiles) are intentionally separate from the second edition.

I don't own the game, so I can't physically confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

I own both editions of the game and you are not missing any cards. The core set comes with 16 cards but only 8 miniatures.

The additional 8 cards are part of the conversion kit that allows you to incorporate those investigators if you owned the first edition of the game. If you don't own it, you can acquire the miniatures and tiles from the **Recurring** **Nightmares** expansion which is is a reprint of the components that can be used in the second edition from the first edition of the game.

The **Suppressed** **Memories** expansion provides the components from the first edition expansions of Call of the Wild and Forbidden Alchemy.

Answer (score -1):

I got it for Xmas too...the 16 investigator cards are from earlier editions and not for the new one. So not sure how to use the app with no investigator cards to give me their stats